# VSC launching bash and not default terminal on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

On opening VSC, it always launches the bash terminal, despite ZSH being set as my default terminal. Is there any way to always launch the default terminal on startup?

My terminal related settings look like this:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-linux",
            "color": "terminal.ansiMagenta"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh",
            "icon": "terminal-linux",
            "color": "terminal.ansiCyan"
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish",
            "icon": "terminal-linux",
            "color": "terminal.ansiBlack"
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-linux",
            "color": "terminal.ansiBlack"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-linux",
            "color": "terminal.ansiBlack"
        },
        "dash": {
            "path": "/bin/dash",
            "icon": "terminal-linux",
            "color": "terminal.ansiBlack"
        },
        "nushell": {
            "path": "/usr/local/bin/nu",
            "icon": "terminal-linux",
            "color": "terminal.ansiGreen"
        },
        "rbash": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/rbash"
        },
        "Radian": {
            "path": "/home/quantalabs/miniconda3/bin/radian",
            "color": "terminal.ansiMagenta",
            "icon": "terminal-linux",
            
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "\"FiraCode Nerd Font\", Monaco"
}
```